# Plotting time-series data from pandas results in ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using `pandas` DataFrame and `matplotlib` to draw three lines in the same figure. The data ought to be correct, but when I try to plot the lines, the code returns a `ValueError`, which is unexpected.

The detail error warning says: `ValueError: view limit minimum -105920.979 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value`. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units

How to fix this error, and plot three lines in the same figure?

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
spot=pd.read_excel('https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist_xls/RWTCd.xls',sheet_name='Data 1',skiprows=2) #this is spot price data


prod=pd.read_excel('https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist_xls/WCRFPUS2w.xls',sheet_name='Data 1',skiprows=2) #this is production data
stkp=pd.read_excel('https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist_xls/WTTSTUS1w.xls',sheet_name='Data 1',skiprows=2) #this is stockpile data

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(spot,label='WTI Crude Oil Price')
ax.plot(prod,label='US Crude Oil Production')
ax.plot(stkp,label='US Crude Oil Stockpile')

plt.legend()
plt.show()

print(spot,prod,stkp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I don't get an error running the code, though I have made a couple of adjustments to the import and the plot.

  - Update `matplotlib` and `pandas`.
  - If you're using Anaconda, at the Anaconda prompt, type `conda update --all`
- Parse the `'Date'` column to datetime and set it as the index.
- Place the legend outside the plot
- Set the `yscale` to `'log'`, because the range of numbers is large.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

spot=pd.read_excel('https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist_xls/RWTCd.xls', sheet_name='Data 1',skiprows=2, parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date') #this is spot price data
prod=pd.read_excel('https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist_xls/WCRFPUS2w.xls', sheet_name='Data 1',skiprows=2, parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date') #this is production data
stkp=pd.read_excel('https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist_xls/WTTSTUS1w.xls', sheet_name='Data 1',skiprows=2, parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date') #this is stockpile data

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(spot, label='WTI Crude Oil Price')
ax.plot(prod, label='US Crude Oil Production')
ax.plot(stkp, label='US Crude Oil Stockpile')

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')

plt.yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

[image]